# Loading the 500.shtml page when there is error

Tags: php, error-handling

file.php

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 0);

if(){
echo 'test';

?>
```

I want to hide the error and to show the 500.shtml page, but i see the google chrome error page.

// 500.shtml

```
      <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
    <HTML><HEAD>
    <TITLE>500 Internal Server Error</TITLE>
    </HEAD><BODY>
    <H1>Internal Server Error</H1>
    The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable 
to complete your request.<P> Please contact the server administrator and 
inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have 
done that may have caused the error.<P> More information about this 
error may be available in the server error log.<P>
    </BODY></HTML>
```

Comment: I know that i have syntax errors!

Comment: Listen to king... chrome users will get the chrome error page.... unless you catch all exceptions and display uour own... hint... `try {} catch(exception){}`

Comment: Do you see the `500.shtml` page in Firefox?

Comment: no in firefox is just white page

Comment: @MarianPetrov Then make sure you've configured Apache correctly with the [`ErrorDocument` directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#errordocument).

Answer (score 1):

Chrome always shows it's own page for 5xx-errors.

Answer (score 1):

[Internet Explorer and Chrome](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_404#Custom_error_pages) display their own error pages when they receive HTTP error codes (such as 500) with an error page [smaller than 512 bytes](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1695).

Increase the size of your error page and it should start appearing in Chrome.

Answer (score -1):

if what?!

```
if()
```

this should be something like this:

```
if(isset($_POST))
```

and missing the end of the hook of the condition, so final code:

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 0);

if(isset($_POST)){
echo 'test';
}

?>
```

Comment: i make a syntax error just to check if it will show the 500.shtml page :)

Comment: you want to customize your error page? create .htaccess and add this:  
`ErrorDocument 500 /errors/500.html`  
create folder errors/ and put file 500.html